# How to parse negative index for slice object to argparse.ArgumentParser

Tags: python, slice, argparse

I would like to give slice string as argument, see below

```
import argparse

def _parse_slice(s):
    a = [int(e) if e.strip() else None for e in s.split(":")]
    return slice(*a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument('-s', type=_parse_slice)
    args = p.parse_args()

    print(args.s)
```

It works fine with positive index, e.g., `-s 1:10`, `-s -5` (which gives rise to `slice[None, -5, None]`) is also fine, but errors out with negative index as first parameter, e.g., `-5:`

```
usage: slice-parse.py [-h] [-s S]
slice-parse.py: error: argument -s: expected one argument
```

How should I support negative index as first slice parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, `argparse` by default does understand the `=` token

```
$ python slice-parse.py -s=-5:
slice(-5, None, None)
```

The reason why `-5` works directly as one might expect is due to `argparse` having [implemented some heuristics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing), which are detailed in the linked documentation (basically `-5` looks like a number, `-5:` does not).

This issue is caused essentially by argparse treating all `-` (by default) as flags.  This can be redefined using [`prefix_chars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars).

Comment: @nos added more details as to why, and updated the answer for that **exact** use case even though it did not change the point...